# Variance Statistics

Tags: statistics, variance

A sample of 10 small debts from a small business were
16.39, 25.09, 16.31, 20.94, 17.58, 19.06, 17.21, 18.48, 16.88, 15.51

[image]

Can someone tell me how they are getting the variance because the xi is confusing me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x_i$ is the $i$-th value of the list $\{16.39, 25.09, 16.31, 20.94, 17.58, 19.06, 17.21, 18.48, 16.88, 15.51\}$

$x_1=16.39, x_2=25.09, \ldots , x_{10}=15.51$ and such.

$\begin{align}\overline x ~=~& \dfrac{\sum x_i}{10}\\[1ex] =~& 1.639 + 2.509 + 1.631 + 2.094 + 1.758 + 1.906 + 1.721 + 1.848 + 1.688 + 1.551\\[1ex] =~& 18.345\end{align}$

$\begin{align}s^2 ~=~& \dfrac{\sum (x_i-\overline x)^2}{9}\\[1ex] =~& \tfrac 19( (16.39-18.345)^2 + (25.09-18.345)^2 + (16.31-18.345)^2 + (20.94-18.345)^2 + (17.58-18.345)^2 + (19.06-18.345)^2 + (17.21-18.345)^2 + (18.48-18.345)^2 + (16.88-18.345)^2 + (15.51-18.345)^2)\\[1ex] \approx.~& 8.087\end{align}$

And so forth.

Most easily done with a spreadsheet application these days.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused about the second part on how you get 8.087 as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $\overline{x}$ is the mean, then the variance is:
$$
{1 \over 9} \left[ (x_{1} - \overline{x})^2 + 
(x_{2} - \overline{x})^2 + \ldots + (x_{10} - \overline{x})^2 \right]
$$
The sum in $[]$'s can also be written
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{10} (x_{k} - \overline{x})^2.
$$